# How to store parameters correctly in a mongodb document?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, nosql

I am looking for a way to store my application settings and I would like to do it in a clear and optimized way. I hesitate between these two ways or if you have another way do not hesitate to tell me

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62d01540f5c83dd3cf40113f"
  },
  "server_id": "989984533623480410",
  "plugins": {
    "welcome": {
      "enabled": false,
      "settings": {
        "send-new-message": true
      }
    },
    "moderation": {
      "enabled": false,
      "settings": {
        "param-1": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62d01540f5c83dd3cf40113f"
  },
  "server_id": "989984533623480410",
  "plugins": {
    "welcome": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "moderation": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "plugins": {
      "moderation": {
        "send-new-message": true
      },
      "welcome": {
        "param-1": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```